# Filter OData through Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, azure

I Create WebService to call OData with Azure App Service, Im able to get the data from OData via Postman. Im Able to Filter the data with hardcode the url.  But now i want to aply filter to get specific data through my webservice. Example here is my OData Url  `public static string sessionUrl1 = "/api/data/v9.0/contacts` , if i want to add filter i will just add the filter in url like this `sessionUrl1 = "/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$filter=fullname eq 'Ken Arok'";` but know i want to filter it through my web service, example my webservice is `http://aloha.azurewebsites.net/`, and i want to filter it through my webservice url like this `http://customroutes.azurewebsites.net/User?$filter=fullname eq 'Ken Arok'"`   How to Achieve this , should i Add Post Method In Web Service ? i already create Post method  but its still does'nt work maybe you Have sugestion What should i add here ?

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("FilterContact")]

        public string GetFilter([FromBody]FilterModel filter)
        {
            filter.Filter = null;
            string GetUserSessionOperationPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", ClientConfiguration.Default.UriString.TrimEnd('/'), sessionUrl + filter.Filter);

            try
            {
                // Creates an HttpWebRequest for user session URL.
                HttpWebRequest aadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetUserSessionOperationPath);

                // Change TLS version of HTTP request if the TLS version value is defined in ClientConfiguration
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ClientConfiguration.OneBox.TLSVersion))
                {
                    aadRequest.ProtocolVersion = Version.Parse(ClientConfiguration.OneBox.TLSVersion);
                }

                string tlsRequestVersion = aadRequest.ProtocolVersion.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("The TLS protocol version for the HTTP request is {0}.", tlsRequestVersion);

                aadRequest.Headers[OAuthHelper.OAuthHeader] = OAuthHelper.GetAuthenticationHeader();
                aadRequest.Method = "GET";
                aadRequest.ContentLength = 0;

                // Get HttpWebResponse for the response
                var aadResponse = (HttpWebResponse)aadRequest.GetResponse();

                string tlsResponseVersion = aadResponse.ProtocolVersion.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("The TLS protocol version of the server response is {0}.", tlsResponseVersion);

                if (aadResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not get response from the server.");
                    //return;
                }

                // Get response string
                using (Stream responseStream = aadResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nSuccessfully received response.\nResponse string: {0}.", responseString));
                        aadResponse.Close();
                        return responseString;
                    }
                }


                // Releases the resources of the response.

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed with the exception: {0} and stack trace: {1}.", ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            //  Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

my Model

```
 public class FilterModel
    {
        public string Filter { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I just created my Web API project to test this issue. You could follow the approaches below to achieve your purpose.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET http://localhost/api/values?$expand=Supplier&$filter=fullname eq 'Ken Arok'
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var dics = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(q=>q.Key,q=>q.Value);
        string filter = null;
        dics.TryGetValue("$filter", out filter);

        //TODO:
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,filter);
        //return Json(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Select(q => new { key = q.Key, value = q.Value }));
    }
}
```

Or

**Model:**

```
public class FilterModel
{
    [JsonProperty("$filter")]
    public string Filter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$expand")]
    public string Expand { get; set; }

    //add other options for OData
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]FilterModel filter)
    {   
        //TODO:
        return Json(filter);
    }
}
```

**TEST:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and im sorry im still very green in this, this is my OData url  _string GetUserSessionOperationPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", ClientConfiguration.Default.UriString.TrimEnd('/'), sessionUrl + filter.Filter);_ as you can see after sessionUrl there a filter.Filter which i  will write in body , is there any method to pass the  value from body to that Odata url ? or can i acieve that from code you write above ? Im sorry but im still dont get it how your code will work in my problem

Comment: The `GetFilter` action is under your web service project, right? If I understood you correctly, you have to pass the OData query options via your web service url, then you need to retrieve the OData query options (e.g. `$filter`,`$select`,etc.) in your `GetFilter` action, then pass the $filter to your real OData API for retrieving the response. I just provided the code snippet for you about how to retrieve the OData options (e.g. the value of `$filter`) passed to your web service endpoint.